# Rename wildcard files in Windows CMD

Tags: windows, cmd, rename, wildcard

I have a bunch of files in a folder, something like:

> file1-regular-exp-suffix1
>   file2-regular-exp-suffix2

...
and so on.

I have tried to rename the files in cmd using a wildcard (*):

```
ren *regular-exp* *new-exp*
```

But this doesn't work. Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Please describe what you mean by "_this doesn't work_", like giving an example of the filenames, the _regular-exp_, the command that you used, and the result that you're getting.

Comment: the files are just a bunch of csv files: 
dallas-stop-and-search-2015.csv
dallas-stop-and-search-2016.csv 
newyork-stop-and-search-2015.csv

and so on... I want to rename every file that has "stop-and-search" in it to: 
dallas-X-2015
dallas-X-2016

Answer (score 0):

Reasonably easy in PowerShell. When you are confident that the files will be renamed correctly, remove the `-WhatIf` from the `Rename-Item` cmdlet.

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Filter '*-stop-and-search-*.csv' |
    ForEach-Object {
        Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName ($_.Name -replace '-stop-and-search','') -WhatIf
    }
```

If you assume positional arguments:

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Filter '*-stop-and-search-*.csv' |
    ForEach-Object {
        Rename-Item $_ ($_ -replace '-stop-and-search','') -WhatIf
    }
```

Comment: When I try the first code in powershell, I get the following message:

What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: C:\Users\allam\desktop\test\Dallas-stop-and-search-02-2016.txt Destination: C:\Users\allam\desktop\test\Dallas-stop-and-search-02-2016.txt".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: C:\Users\allam\desktop\test\Dallas-thing-stop-and-search-2018-08.txt Destination: C:\Users\allam\desktop\test\Dallas--2018-08.txt".

but nothing happens?

Comment: The `-WhatIf` tells you what would happen if the rename was done. If this is the correct rename, then remove the `-WhatIf` switch from the `Rename-Item` cmdlet line. Using `-WhatIf` allows you to see what would happen if the command were actually done.

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes your files are always of the form:
**[place]**-stop-and-search-**[year].csv**

You can use [`FOR /F`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) to split the filename first using the "-" as the delimiter.

```
for /f "tokens=1,5 delims=-" %i in ('dir /b *stop-and-search*.csv') do rename "%i-*-%j" "%i-X-%j"
```

The command [`dir /b *stop-and-search*.csv`](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) will get all a list of all the matching filenames.

The [`delims=-`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) option will split the filename on each "-" character.
The [`tokens=1,5`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) selects the first and last tokens and assigns them to `%%i` and `%%j`.
So for example, for "dallas-stop-and-search-2016.csv", `i=dallas` and `j=2016.csv`.

Then inside the loop, execute the same rename command but you can now explicitly specify the first and last parts using the tokens `%i` and `%j`.

If you want to put it into a batch file, use `%%` instead of `%` for the variable names.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,5 delims=-" %%i in ('dir /b *stop-and-search*.csv') do (
    rename "%%i-*-%%j" "%%i-X-%%j"
)
```